# how to properly import django project settings to interact with app's ORM?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to interact with django app ORM from outer script, but when i

```
(Pdb) import myapp.settings
(Pdb) from django.conf import settings
(Pdb) settings.configure(myapp.settings)
(Pdb) from app.models import MyModel
*** AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE'
```

how to properly import django app settings, to query the ORM data in cases like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was solved by

```
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
    django.setup()
```

after that, i imported the ORMs and the models objects worked!

Answer (score 1):

Before running the program, please set PYTHONPATH variable to include your django project dir.

Suppose you have you django project in:
/home/anon/mydjangoproject

Then, before running your application, ensure you have:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/anon/mydjangoproject
```

These examples work in a Linux shell, please do a similar system environment variable setting for any other operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem while trying to build a background schedule cron job on Django 1.10.0

I fixed the issue by declaring the following on the top of the standalone script

```
import os, django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","myapp.settings")
django.setup()
#continue with the rest of your code
```

Hope this will fix the issue. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a project level connection

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

from app.model import ModelName
orm = ModelName.objects.all()
print(orm)
```

Next you can import models and execute django orm's ,
It was tested in django 1.11.6

Thanks.....!